# Should web API controller actions that perform no async work always be declared as async?

Tags: web-api, asp.net-core, async

I have been going over our app web api and making sure all async work is async all the way - and no artificial [asynchronicity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asynchrony#:%7E:text=(%CB%8C)%C4%81%2D%CB%88si%C5%8B%2Dkr%C9%99%2D%CB%8Cni%2Dz%C9%99m,lack%20of%20concurrence%20in%20time) is enforced.

Say I have the following web api controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Foo()
    {
        //no async work
        return OK(...);
    }
```

I planned to remove the async keyword from actions like the one above - those that do not perform any async work - changing it to

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Foo()
    {
        //no async work
        return OK(...);
    }
```

Then one of my teammates claims controller actions should be always async.
I could not find explicit evidence over the internet for this argument - but even if it is true, it has the drawback of polluting my solution by adding `CS1998` warnings (*This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread*) all over (One can suppress those, but, I find it contradictory that on the one hand it would be a best practice to have them async, and on the other compiler will raise a flag indicating something needs attention on these).

Is it really a good practice to have non-async controller actions - async ?

Comment: `Then one of my teammates claims controller actions should always be async` did he or she give you any argument?

Comment: He thinks this enhances scalability. AFAIU, the idea is that using async *enforces* asp.net core to use the async/await model over the old asp.net one-thread-per-request model. If this is really true, sounds like a good argument. I just could not find clear evidence on that. And if this is the case, as I state in the question's body - the rosalyn should take that into consideration and not show such warnings... ?

Comment: @Veverke *"using async enforces asp.net core to use the async/await model"* - this is incorrect I'm afraid; the `async` keyword by itself (without an `await`) does no such thing, it merely enables the `await` keyword, nothing more - certainly nothing to do with threads (while it changes the method return type so that the result is wrapped in a `Task`, `Task` by itself does not alter behaviour).  if `await` isn't used, then it is merely a plain synchronous method.   Stephen Cleary's blog has a good, in-depth explanation: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: @BenCottrell: thanks Ben, that's what I thought, when I heard that at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is one of those things that doesn't concretely matter enough to die on either hill; but developers tend to err one way or another. I, for one, err the other way than you. This answer is my reasoning, but at the end of the day both our approaches yield working solutions, there is no right and wrong here.

---

Taking a bit of a detour, let's refresh our definition of encapsulation. We abstract away the concrete, in order for the consumer to no longer be attached to the concrete implementation but rather the *contract*.
The idea here is that by doing so, we are about to swap out our implementation *without* impacting the consumer, as long as we can adhere to the contract that the consumer was built to work with.

Again a small detour, I want to focus on methods in general for a second, not just API endpoints. I reckon the spirit of encapsulation is best continued by making all signatures async, because then the concrete implementation is free to choose whether it implements a synchronous or an asynchronous solution.

In a sense, having a synchronous signature reveals to the consumer that you are working synchronously. If you ever need to work asynchronously, you need to disrupt the established contract. Vice versa, this would not have been a problem, as you could have made a previously async method synchronous without needing to disrupt the contract.

Therefore, erring towards async signatures is more change-friendly than only using them when the concrete need arises, which is why I'm in favor of sticking with a consistent async signature once my application is predominantly async.

Focusing back to API endpoints, the argument is slightly weaker, since the framework handles async/sync endpoints for you. There is no real consumer that you need to take care of since the consumer is .NET and it can adapt to either.
Maybe you consider that a reason to ignore the above reasoning. I could see how you get there. But I am a stickler for consistency in a codebase, and since the same reasoning applies, even if only on principle, I prefer to keep things consistent instead of introducing exceptional sync cases here and there.

Are there exception to this? Of course. Not every extension method or helper class I write is therefore async, because there are some cases where the remit of the class is clearly not of an asynchronous nature. This is not a dogma nor a blanket statement, and I'm not trying to sell it as such.

---

**Update** To be clear, because I notice from the comments that this was left too ambiguous, I am not suggesting you use the `async` keyword everywhere. My focus here is on the contracts being async-oriented.

The `async` keyword doesn't impact the contract (you can freely change it without forcing the consumer to make any change), but things like adding/removing the `Task<T>` return type, passing a `CancellationToken`, ... *does* impact the contract, and it's those things that I would add even if you know that the method body is currently synchronous.

In other words, I would leave the method differently than either of your examples. I would be more inclined to do:

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IActionResult> Foo()
{
    IActionResult result = OK(...);
    return Task.FromResult(result); 
}
```

No `async` keyword since there is no `await` happening. However, I did keep the `Task<T>` return type as this forms part of the contract.

---

As an aside, I think part of this is due to async only having appeared on the stage much later than when synchronous execution did.

Because of it, using an async signature feels like doing something extra on top of the (synchronous) baseline, which in turn triggers developers' need to be efficient and makes them go "why would I do this extra thing when I don't need it right now? YAGNI!".

I think that's the wrong way around. I think our baseline should be the most permissive options, in this case async (which, as established), can also house sync operations). We should only strengthen the condition to only allow async when there are cases where we either clearly don't need or explicitly want to disallow asynchronous execution.

Had we have had async right from the get go with sync, I reckon we wouldn't have thought about async as a quirky extra. But we didn't, and so we don't use async as the baseline since we were first taught synchronous operations. Maybe the next generation of developers will be different now that async is here to stay.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to leave your bits. I am with at `I prefer to keep things consistent instead of introducing exceptional sync cases here and there`. But you missed the main reasoning on why not to do that - in my case. Interestingly, my main motivation for not using async is not what you describe - I am coming from a "let's make my solution warning-free". I am assuming warnings are reliable, am assuming that the .NET team had more good reasons when deciding this should be a warning - than me. (continued below)

Comment: (continuation) This may not be true, and I can then understand I should be ignoring these CS1998 warnings (forcefully instructing compiler to ignore them).

Comment: "Async as default" is called **multithreading** and it turned out to not be that great of an idea.

Comment: @Veverke I'm with you when it comes to warnings.  In fact the first thing I do when creating a proejct is enable 'treat warnings as errors', and then stomp every single one out.

Comment: @user253751 Asynchrony and multithreading are two distinct concepts. You can write async code that utilizes a single thread. Realistically, that's not a constraint people work with, but it proves the point that asynchrony is not "called multithreading" as you suggest.

Comment: @Veverke: I'll amend this in the answer because I understand that this was left ambiguous, but I wasn't suggesting you use the `async` keyword everywhere - my focus was on the contracts being async-oriented. The `async` keyword doesn't impact the contract (you can freely change it without forcing the consumer to make any change), but things like adding/removing the `Task<T>` return type, passing a `CancellationToken`, ... _does_ impact the contract, and it's those things that I would add even if you know that the method body is currently synchronous.

Comment: @Veverke [..] This way, you avoid the warning, which is what you want. But at the same time you also make sure your contract is as agnostic as it can be in regards to the concrete implementation actually being asynchronous or not.

Comment: It seems better practice (to me) to treat the change from sync to async (or vice-versa) as a versioning concern. This offers the best of both worlds as one can add/remove the Async name suffix so that name matches intent, etc.

Comment: @Flater: not sure we are talking about the same thing, but if I leave a method signature as `async Task<T> Foo`, and the method body has no awaits, then I **do get the warning**. Again, I think both your points of a) being consistent throughout all API contracts and b) choosing the option more likely to **minimize** changes in API contracts - but as I state before - a method declared as `async Task<T> Foo`, with a body without awaits, **generates CS1998 warning**.

Comment: @Flater: I understand ultimately I have to choose a side here. .NET compiler team cared more about **consistently issuing warnings** than consistence in API contracts. You make the point of the other way around. If I choose your side, then I must turn off CS1998s. If I prefer not to let go off CS1998, then I do let go off keeping contracts consistent across the system + minimizing contracts change whenever possible.

Comment: @Flater Async *as default*, however, is the same as multithreading, but slower.

Comment: My biggest complaint about async by default is the syntactical overhead of an additional keyword in the method signature (`async`) and a weird return type (`Task<T>`) which consuming code uses as if it returned `T` instead of `Task<T>`. Or more tersely: laziness. And I don't like unnecessarily weird things, and `Task<T>` without the implementation needing async operations just seems unnecessary. But I do like your point about sync operations being the baseline of what were taught, and is therefore my bias when encountering async language constructs. (also +1 for your answer)

Comment: @Veverke: You may have glossed over the fact that you can have a method that returns a `Task<T>` (therefore being async-friendly) but _without_ using the `async` keyword. That is what I am suggesting. Adding/removing the `async` keyword does not change the contract, and therefore the `async` keyword is not part of what I'd suggest you do in order to remain async-friendly even if the current implementation is synchronous. If you omit the `async` keyword (aside: which means you'll have to wrap your returned value in `Task.FromResult(...)`), you will not get the warning.

Comment: @user253751: As with all things, highly tailoring something can squeeze out extra performance but comes at a significant cost of effort and risk of shooting yourself in the foot; and in this case the potential for broken contracts which may require effort to fix from the consumer's end. Unless you are working with hard constraints (i.e. functional requirements) that necessitate the kind of performance you can only get from squeezing and dedicated tailoring, I strongly advocate to maximize the maintainability and change-friendliness of the code.

Comment: @JasonWeber: Not saying it can't be done the way you suggest, but versioning is a necessary evil that exists to deal with the breaking of a contract. _Not breaking a contract to begin with_ is even better. I'm also not a fan of the "async" suffix _unless_ you have competing sync and async alternatives for the same method. Once you assume async by default, the "async" suffix ceases to be useful. This is, in my opinion, a variation on why Hungarian notation has gone out of style. We should not be baking technical details into the human-readable name we use.

Comment: @Flater Appreciate many of your contributions here. Versioning is the communication of a changed contract. It's as much a part of the contract as any other element. There are several ways to do this, and I prefer the most direct one. Using any of them is better than using none. "Not breaking the contract" isn't on the menu in this case given the signature is changing. I agree that a consistent suffix across all method names instances is useless (conveys no info). However, it's unlikely that we'll see this in .NET anytime soon given the large number of methods that would gain no benefit.

Comment: @Flater That said, suffix usage (or not) is more a matter of convention/style/taste than an objectively good engineering practice across all teams.

Comment: @JasonWeber _"Not breaking the contract" isn't on the menu in this case given the signature is changing._ Au contraire, if you follow my suggestion. My suggestion is to specifically stick with the `Task<>` return type and `CancellationToken` parameter (even if it's currently a synchronous method), which means that you wouldn't need to break the contract even if you make it async. `async` (the keyword) is not part of the signature of a method. I do appreciate your stance and it definitely reflects how many developers now approach it at the moment. I just think there's room for improvement here.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: I reckon that if people genuinely embraced the "async as default" approach, that this could be used to argue that the language should implicitly infer the `Task<>` and `await` constructs (i.e. the compiler can just add them on without requiring the developer to do so). I doubt the C# developers are going to introduce this kind of breaking change, but it's possible to do so (or create a variant language that does so).